# Force implicit response types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I started learning TypeScript and can't figure out (if that's even possible) the way to have implicit response types and avoid having to import them in all client services to cast response data. Response types (JwtTokens in this example) would be defined in the API service itself.

What I've done so far is to assign generics for API's endpoints creator method. I know I'm misunderstanding something here, as this obviously still forces the client (auth service) to declare the type of the response.

```js
/* services/api.service/types.ts */

export type EndpointsCreator = (instance: AxiosInstance) => {
  [key: string]: <T>(args: any) => Promise<T>; // <-- Generics here to allow response type declaration
};

export type Credentials = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

export type JwtTokens = {
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
};
```

```js
/* services/api.service/index.ts */

import axios from 'axios';
import auth from './auth.endpoints';

const instance = axios.create();

export default {
  auth: auth(instance),
};
```

```js
/* services/api.service/auth.endpoints.ts */

import type { EndpointsCreator, Credentials, JwtTokens } from './types';
import config from './config';

const authEndpoints: EndpointsCreator = instance => {
  // const loginUser = async <JwtTokens>(credentials: Credentials): Promise<JwtTokens> => {  <-- This not working
  const loginUser = async (credentials: Credentials): Promise<JwtTokens> => {
    const { email, password } = credentials;
    if (!email || !password) throw new Error('MISSING_CREDENTIALS');
    const { data } = await instance.post<JwtTokens>(config.resources.LOGIN, credentials);
    return data;
  };

  return { loginUser };
};

export default authEndpoints;
```

```js
/* services/auth.service.ts */

import api, { Credentials, JwtTokens } from '@/services/api.service'; // <-- Ideally avoid having to import JwtTokens here

export const login = async (credentials: Credentials) => {
  const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await api.auth.loginUser<JwtTokens>(credentials); // <-- Ideally avoid having to use JwtTokens here
  tokenRefresher.setTokens(accessToken, refreshToken);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want to say that I saw something new to me in this code samples. You using *at sign* in your import path. I am not sure how this affects typescripts ability to import types, but judging by what I googled about it, it seems like this can work if you configure ts-loaders properly in webpack config file.

```
import api, { Credentials, JwtTokens } from '@/services/api.service';
```

Also you forgot to export `authEndpoints` function in `services/api.service/auth.endpoints.ts` and mistyped name of function in `import auth from './auth.endpoints';` in `services/api.service/index.ts`. Should be `import { authEndpoints } from './auth.endpoints';`.

With this being said I'll move to main question. You've actually did right almost everything except using type `EndpointsCreator`. You don't need it, at least not as its declared. Get rid of it and return type of `loginUser` will be automatically inferred by typescript because it is already known inside of function at the point when you pass It as type argument to `instance.post<JwtTokens>`. You also don't need type `Promise<JwtTokens>`.

Here is how is should look like:

```
export const authEndpoints = instance => {
  const loginUser = async (credentials: Credentials) => {
    const { email, password } = credentials;
    if (!email || !password) throw new Error('MISSING_CREDENTIALS');
    const { data } = await instance.post<JwtTokens>(config.resources.LOGIN, credentials);
    return data;
  };

  return { loginUser };
};
```

Now returning type will be known in `services/api.service/index.ts` and `services/auth.service.ts`.

---

If you want to create common contract for all endpointCreators, that for example will constrain arguments that they accept, in this case in `instance: AxiosInstance` you can do it with classes like this, this way wherever you import endpointCreators you will have them with precise type info about signature of every method they have at the same time they all will have same contract specified in BaseEndpointCreator.

```
/* services/api.service/types.ts */

import { AxiosInstance } from "axios"

export abstract class BaseEndpointCreator {
  constructor(protected readonly instance: AxiosInstance) {}
}

export type Credentials = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

export type JwtTokens = {
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
};
```

and

```
/* services/api.service/auth.endpoints.ts */
import { BaseEndpointCreator, Credentials, JwtTokens } from './types';
import { AxiosInstance } from "axios"
import config from './config';


export class AuthEndpoints extends BaseEndpointCreator {
  async loginUser(credentials: Credentials): Promise<JwtTokens> {
    const { email, password } = credentials;
    if (!email || !password) throw new Error('MISSING_CREDENTIALS');
    const { data } = await this.instance.post<JwtTokens>(config.resources.LOGIN, credentials);
    return data;
  };
}
```

and

```
/* services/api.service/index.ts */

import axios from 'axios';
import auth from './auth.endpoints';

const instance = axios.create();


export default {
  auth: new AuthEndpoints(instance),
};
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot to write the default export of the enpoint module. I've edited the question to fix it. The at sign is the convention for resolving aliases, at least in Vite.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Getting rid of all type stuff works perfectly. However, the idea behind the EndpointsCreator type was to have a contract for all other endpoint creators to come, so I could centralize it in some kind of Factory. Isn't that the main reason for using TypeScript?

Comment: As I understand the only common thing between endpointCreators is that they all have one AxiosInstace argument, but returning object will be with different for each endpointCreator. If so you can declare abstract class BaseEndpointCreator which will accept in it constructor AxiosInstance and all other endpointCreators will extend BaseEndpointCreator and add their specific methods for requests. This way you will be able to keep type info about all methods anywhere you import endpointCreators, same time they will only accept AxiosInstance as only argument

Comment: I updated answer and added some code samples